# Instanciar um objeto relacionado a outro objeto C#?

Tags: c#, classes, relacionamento

Eu tenho duas classes: Categoria e Subcategoria

```
public class Categoria
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public List<Subcategoria> Subcategoria { get; set; }
}
```

e a classe sub:

```
public class Subcategoria
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Consigo instanciar um objeto de categoria, mas e como eu faço para criar um de subcategoria? Que será dependente de categoria.

E caso eu cadastre mais de um, como faço para percorre-los?

Supondo que eu tenha uma lista de categorias:

```
List<Categoria> categorias = new List<Categoria>();
categorias.Add(new Categoria { Nome = "FILMES", Subcategoria = })
```

Observação: não consegui desenvolver para preencher o "subcategoria" e  não sei qual termo utilizar para pesquisar, pois, falando em "relacionamento" de classes, só vem sobre `Entity Framework`, mas gostaria entender dessa forma, que é a mais simples.

Comment: Para ser prestada uma boa orientação precisamos de mais contexto, como informações sobre casos de usos e regras de negócio relativas a essas classes.

Comment: Então, no caso esse é somente um exemplo. eu gostaria de ter uma categoria, e poder cadastrar N subcategorias dentro dela. E não sei qual a sintaxe para fazer isto. Criar um objeto de Categoria, e criar por exemplo, 2 subcategorias para ela.

Comment: Tem duas formas de fazer isso: A forma correta e a gambiarra. Para fazer uma gambiarra é fácil só escrever um código acoplando as classes de qualquer jeito que basta passar no teste do Run que foi. Para fazer de forma correta é preciso de um mínimo de entendimento do cenário de uso dessas classes, um mínimo de entendimento sobre o relacionamento dos *objetos* criados a partir dessas classes. Por exemplo: não sei se duas categorias podem compartilhar uma mesma instancia de subcategoria,  não sei o que implica em uma categoria possuir uma subcategoria,  não sei o que esta sendo categorizado,...

Comment: Na classe SubCategoria você pode adicionar uma propriedade do tipo Categoria, além de um construtor que receba uma Categoria. Assim uma SubCategoria nunca poderá ser instanciada de forma errada.

Comment: É impressionante, falaram e até responderam como é para ser feito mas em nenhum momento foi citado SOLID ou algum design pattern seja criacional, estrutural ou comportamental. Vocês estão ensinando a fazerem Golden Hammer.

Answer (score -1):

Tem várias formas de vc preencher a subcategoria:

Uma delas é:

```
List<Categoria> categorias = new List<Categoria>();
categorias.Add(new Categoria
{
    Nome = "FILMES",
    Subcategoria = new List<Subcategoria>()
    {
        new Subcategoria() { Nome = "nome1" },
        new Subcategoria() { Nome = "nome2" },
        new Subcategoria() { Nome = "nome3" },
        new Subcategoria() { Nome = "nome4" },
        new Subcategoria() { Nome = "nome5" },
        new Subcategoria() { Nome = "nome6" },
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma forma simples que uso e sempre dar certo é transforma os objetos em lista e ir adicionando outros objetos;

/*No Model ou objeto da classe Filme deve estar +/- dessa forma*/

```
public virtual <List> Caterogias { get; set; }
public string TituloFilme {get; set;}
public string Autor {get; set;}
```

/*Lista de Objetos*/

```
List<Filmes> ListaFilme = new List<Filmes>();
List<Caterogias> ListaCategoria = new List<Categorias>();
```

/*Criar objetos para popular a lista de objetos*/

```
Categorias ObjCategoria = new Categorias
{
   TipoFilme = "Terro",
   DuracaoMinutos = 120,
};

ListaCategoria.add(ObjCategoria);

Filmes objFilme = new Filmes
{
   Titulo = "Crepusculo",
   Autor = "Desconhecido",
   Categoria = ListaCategoria,
};

ListaFilme.add(objFilme);
```

Dessa forma você consegue de forma organizada a preencher as listas de catergorias e as do Filme, e quando for instanciar se não tiver muitos você mesmo pode criar uma consulta de filmes dentro do código dessa forma. ListaFilme[0].Titulo == "Crepusculo" && ListaFilme[0].Categoria[0].TipoFilme == "Terro".

Espero pode ter ajudado!